# please not VS please don't VS please not to

Tags: syntax

1. Please not tell me.
2. Please don't tell me.
3. Please not to tell me.

---

- Are they all proper English,
- which should be preferred?

Comment: Only #2 is idiomatically acceptable English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is:

`Please  ... [ (do)(do not) ] {bare infinitive}`<sup>†</sup>

where the values in the brackets [ ] are optional.

Please stay.

Please do stay.

Please do not stay.

Please go.

Please do go.

Please do not go.

Please tell me.

Please do tell me.

Please do not tell me.

<sup>†</sup>The bare infinitive does not have **to**

Comment: Note that *do not* (emphatic) can be contracted to *don't* (neutral).

Comment: Thx. This is the first time to hear of [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) (I get it now)

Comment: Imperative constructions use the bare infinitive form of the verb.  *Jump!*  And instead of using the marked infinitive in your comment just now (**to hear**) you should use a tensed (finite) form of the verb: **I have heard**.